# jQuery UI Sortable and Cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

I must admit, that I'm pretty much newbie to jQuery, though I want to somehow make this work.

I have a igoogle style content with sortable widgets with this code

### HTML

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            Header Widget
        </div>
                  <div class="box-content">
            <p>
            Content widget
            </p>
               </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div class="column">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
                Header Widget
            </div>
                      <div class="box-content">
                <p>
                Content widget
                </p>
                   </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: '.column',
        handle: '.box-header',
        revert: 500
    });
```

How do I get this work with cookie plugin?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to store the last column the user sorted by in a cookie?

Comment: Well I should be maybe more specific. Here is the preview http://os2.jopixel.cz. The one column is floating left and the other one is floating right, in the right column, there would be more boxes. And what I just want to achieve is to store the layout in to a cookie and then load it after user refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, download the cookie plug-in (if you haven't already):
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie

Next, read this short article that explains how to use the plug-in:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Finally, decide what information you want to store between page loads, and then hook up events to save that info whenever appropriate.  To use that information, add an onReady event that looks it up and does something with it.

For instance, if you wanted to keep track of which column is in which order, you would need to put some IDs on those columns, then do:

```
$(".column").sortable({
  connectWith: '.column',
  handle: '.box-header',
  revert: 500
  update: function(event, ui) {
    // This will trigger after a sort is completed
    var ordering = "";
    var $columns = $(".column");
    $columns.each(function() {
      ordering += this.id + "=" + $columns.index(this) + ";";
    });
    $.cookie("ordering", ordering);
  }
});
```

and then do something like the following to use that information:

```
$(function() {
  var ordering = $.cookie("ordering");
  var orderings = ordering.split(";");
  $.each(orderings, function(index, ordering) {
    // Use each ordering, which will be in the form of "someId=someIndex" to actually
    // sort your stuff.  Not super-familiar with the Sortable package so you'll have to look
    // this part up on your own ... or just use basic jQuery stuff
  };
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224698/initializing-jquery-ui-sortable-list-in-pre-defined-order ?

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try This

```
var setSelector = "#list1";
var setCookieName = "listOrder";
var setCookieExpiry = 7;


// function that writes the list order to a cookie
function getOrder() {
    // save custom order to cookie
    $.cookie(setCookieName, $(setSelector).sortable("toArray"), { expires: setCookieExpiry, path: "/" });
}

// function that restores the list order from a cookie
function restoreOrder() {
    var list = $(setSelector);
    if (list == null) return

    // fetch the cookie value (saved order)
    var cookie = $.cookie(setCookieName);
    if (!cookie) return;

    // make array from saved order
    var IDs = cookie.split(",");

    // fetch current order
    var items = list.sortable("toArray");

    // make array from current order
    var rebuild = new Array();
    for ( var v=0, len=items.length; v<len;>
        rebuild[items[v]] = items[v];
    }

    for (var i = 0, n = IDs.length; i &lt; n; i++) {


        var itemID = IDs[i];

        if (itemID in rebuild) {


            var item = rebuild[itemID];

            var child = $("ul.ui-sortable").children("#" + item);

            var savedOrd = $("ul.ui-sortable").children("#" + itemID);

            child.remove();

            $("ul.ui-sortable").filter(":first").append(savedOrd);
        }
    }
}

// code executed when the document loads
$(function() {

    $(setSelector).sortable({
        axis: "y",
        cursor: "move",
        update: function() { getOrder(); }
    });

    restoreOrder();
});
```

Saved In cookie

Quotes from
 [Shopdev](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/)

Answer (score 1):

I saw lot's of things on this topic everywhere on the Internet. I found them not very accurate and extensive. 
For the record, here is the solution I choose, for a multi-column, portlet dashboard (as in Jquery-UI example).
First of all build the columns and portlets.

```
$( ".ui-portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" );
$( ".ui-column .ui-portlet" ).find( ".ui-portlet-header" )
              .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
              .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
              .end()
      .find( ".ui-portlet-content" );
$( ".ui-portlet .ui-portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".ui-portlet:first" ).find( ".ui-portlet-content" ).toggle("blind", "fast");
      return false;
});
$( ".ui-column" ).disableSelection();
```

Then most importante thing give Id's to every elements (columns, portlets...).

```
$( ".ui-column" ).each(function(index, domEle){ $(domEle).attr('id', 'column_'+index)})
$( ".ui-column .ui-portlet" ).each(function(index, domEle){ $(domEle).attr('id', 'portlet_'+index)})
```

Then make the thing sortable, with an on update event function to set a cookie after each displacement.

```
$( ".ui-column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".ui-column",
      handle: '.ui-portlet-header',
      update: function(event, ui) {
          var cooked = new Array;
          $( ".ui-column" ).each(function(index, domEle){ cooked[index]= $(domEle).sortable('toArray')});
          $.cookie('cookie_name', cooked.join('|'), { expires: 7, path: '/'});
      }
});
```

Now the restoreOrder function.

```
function restoreOrder() {
    var cookie = $.cookie('cookie_name');
    if (!cookie) return;
    var SavedID = cookie.split('|');
    for ( var u=0, ul=SavedID.length; u &lt; ul; u++ ){ SavedID[u] = SavedID[u].split(',');}
    for (var Scolumn=0, n = SavedID.length; Scolumn &lt; n; Scolumn++) {
        for (var Sitem=0, m = SavedID[Scolumn].length; Sitem &lt; m; Sitem++) {
            $(".ui-column").eq(Scolumn).append($(".ui-column").children("#" + SavedID[Scolumn][Sitem]));
        }
    }
}
// TODO check why an empty column crash the loops !? Should not be complicate...
```

And off course after you load your document `restoreOrder()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Elmatou. Just a dirty fix that worked for me (just a letter before you fill the cookie).

```
$( ".ui-column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".ui-column",
      handle: '.ui-portlet-header',
      update: function(event, ui) {
          var cooked = new Array;
          $( ".ui-column" ).each(function(index, domEle){ cooked[index]= $(domEle).sortable('toArray')});
          $.cookie('cookie_name', 'x'+cooked.join('|'), { expires: 7, path: '/'});
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well now I can get an array like this,

```
function saveOrder() {
    var cookieName = "order";
     $.cookie(cookieName, $(".column").each(function(){ $(this).sortable("toArray")}));
    }
```

and then

```
$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
        handle: '.box-header',
        revert: 500,
        update: function(event, ui) {
        saveOrder();

  }
```

Now how to retrieve it from the cookie?

Comment: >>Now how to retrieve it from the cookie?
var sortableToArray = $.cookie("order");

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that uses localStorage to save the order. 
See example, first the elements need an id. This id will be stored and used in restoring the ordering.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bartburkhardt/2wgnsc2v

```
      $(function() {

        //add id's to the li elements so after sorting we can save the order in localstorage
        $( "#sortable>li" ).each(function(index, domEle){ $(domEle).attr('id', 'item_'+index)});

        $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
          placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
          update: function(event, ui) {        
            localStorage.setItem("sorted",  $("#sortable").sortable("toArray") );
          }
        });

        restoreSorted();

      });


      function restoreSorted(){

          var sorted = localStorage["sorted"];      
          if(sorted == undefined) return;

          var elements = $("#sortable");
          var sortedArr = sorted.split(",");

          for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++){
              var el = elements.find("#" + sortedArr[i]);
              $("#sortable").append(el);
          };

      }

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">block 12</li>
</ul>
```