# Read back sortable order from cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a "portlet"-style dashboard that uses the jQuery UI "sortable" interaction, and I would like to read back a locally-stored state on page load. So as I move portlets around on the page, when I leave and return to the page, I want them to be in the same location. I need to do this client-side ("local preferences") rather than push the state change to the server.

Saw this Question here: [jQuery UI Sortable and Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370417/jquery-ui-sortable-and-cookie)

And although it had some good pointers, I can't help but wondering if I'm missing something more fundamental... it's been a few years and maybe there are better included tools.

I've gotten somewhere with this update function:

```js
update : function(e,ui) {
  // where "shortname" is a unique string identified elsewhere on the page
  localConfig.layout[shortname] = [];
  var containers = $('.widgetContainer');
  containers.each(function(){
    localConfig.layout[shortname].push($(this).sortable("toArray"));
  });
}
```

This results in an array of arrays thus:

`[["someWidget", "anotherWidget"],["widgetInOtherColumn", "anotherWidgetInOtherColumn"]]`

I won't bore you with the code, but I know for sure I can set this in localStorage (or cookie if not available). So storing it will get added to the above code.

The real question is simply this:

Is there a simple or built-in mechanism for reading my array of arrays back, using the jQuery UI API? Or do I have to go in "by hand", grabbing the array and iterating over them to move the DOM nodes around? And I mean the above code doesn't even need to stick around. The jQuery UI "Tabs" widget just has an argument you can pass (`cookie: {args}` ... not sure why it's not in the API, but it works!); does sortable have something similar either included in jQUI or as a plugin?

If it's only possible by writing a new method, what is the most efficient way to shuffle nodes around? Left to my own devices, I would grab all the nodes, move them into some storage container, and then move them back to where they need to be via an iterator. Seems to me there must be a less involved way of switching the order of elements than that.

Thanks!

Comment: Still not clear what you want, can you give example of "input" and "output"?

Comment: @Hogan thanks for reading. I updated the introduction paragraph to try and clarify. If you go to the link now provided, you'll see what I mean by "portlets". I need the ability to re-order these and have the changes persist between pageloads. The state changes will be stored locally rather than pushed up to the server.