# Getting sorted div from cookie with Sortable and Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-ui-sortable

Afternoon all,

I am having a bit of an issue reading values from a cookie when the page is (re)loaded.

I have been able to use the following code to set a cookie value of 'ordering' when the divs are switched:

```
$(function()
        {
            $("#sort").sortable({
                containment: "parent",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                opacity: 0.7,
                cursor: "move",
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    $.cookie("ordering", $('#sort').sortable("toArray"), {expires: 365, path: '/'});
                }
            });
        });
```

I have checked the cookie after the divs are changed and the order changes in the cookie

However, when I load the page the divs are in their original position.

I have had a look at [jQuery UI Sortable and Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370417/jquery-ui-sortable-and-cookie) and tried to implement the changes suggested there and when I look in Firebug it throws up an error stating:

"Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'toArray'
throw new Error( msg );"

Not quite sure where I am going wrong.

This is what I have for the reading of the cookie and setting of the new order

```
function restoreOrder()
        {
            var list = $("#sort");
            var cookie = $.cookie("ordering");
            var cid = cookie.split(",");
            var items = list.sortable("toArray");
            console.log(cid);

            var rebuild = new Array();
            for (var v=0; len=items.length; v<len)
            {
                rebuild[items[v]] = items[v];
            }

            for (var i=0, n=cid.length; i<n; i++)
            {
                var iid = cid[i];
                if (iid in rebuild)
                {
                    var item = rebuild[iid];
                    var child = $("ul.ui-sortable").children("#" + item);
                    var savedOrd = $("ul.ui-sortable").children("#" + iid);
                    child.remove()
                    $("ul.ui-sortable").filter(":first").append(savedOrd);
                }
            }   
        }

        // code executed when the document loads
        $(function() {
            restoreOrder();
        });
```

No matter what I do, it throws up the exception and will not allow the cookie to be read.

Here are some of the divs in question

```
<div id="iptc-sort">
            <div class="caption"><h3></h3><p>IPTC Information</p></div>
            <div class="contentbox">
                {iptc_info}
            </div>
            <div class="contentbottom"></div>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="exif-sort">
            <div id="exifinfo" class="caption"><h3><i class="fa fa-fw fa-2x fa-plus-square-o"></i></h3><p>EXIF Information</p></div>
            <div id="exif" class="contentbox">
                {exif_info}
            </div>
            <div class="contentbottom"></div>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="gmap-sort">
            <div id="mapinfo" class="caption"><h3><i class="fa fa-fw fa-2x fa-plus-square-o"></i></h3><p>Map Information</p></div>
            <div id="map" class="contentbox">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="google">
                            <div id="map_canvas" class="map_canvas"></div>
                            {google_map}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="contentbottom"></div>
            <br/>
        </div>
```

Is there something simple I am missing? I understand I will have to change the naming of the classes used in child and savedOrd

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it after several hours of tweaking it

```
/* Set Cookie */
        var sortablelistSelector = "#sort";
        var sortablelistCookieName = "ordering";
        var sortablelistCookieExp = 365;
        function sortablelistOrder() 
        {
            $.cookie(sortablelistCookieName, $(sortablelistSelector).sortable("toArray"), {expires: sortablelistCookieExp, path: "/"});
        }
        function sortablelistRestoreOrder() 
        {
            var i, previousorder, cookie = $.cookie(sortablelistCookieName);
            if (!cookie)
            {
                return;
            }
            previousorder = cookie.split(',');
            for (i = 0; i < previousorder.length; i++)
            {
                $('#'+previousorder[i]).appendTo($(sortablelistSelector));
            }
        }

        /* Read Cookie */
        $(function()
        {
            $(sortablelistSelector).sortable(
            {
                cursor: "move",
                containment: "parent",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                opacity: 0.7,
                update: function(event, ui)
                {
                    sortablelistOrder();
                }
            });
            sortablelistRestoreOrder();
        });
```